# Ajax response datetime-picker click event not binded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a 'challenge' with the JQuery code after the Ajax response is rendered. This is my JQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/somedomain/shoppingcart/add",
                data: { "name": name},
                success: function(data) {
                    $.get("/some-domain/shoppingcart/show", function(cart){ 
                        $(".shopping-cart").html(cart); 
                    });
                }
            }); 



    $(".shopping-cart").on('click','#orderDate', function() {
            $("#orderDate").datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                minDate: date,
                locale: 'nl'
            });
        });
});

<div class='input-group date' id='orderDate'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
     <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </span>
</div>
```

The problem is that I have to click two times on the datepicker until it opens, this behaviour is only happening when using above code. What am I missing?

Comment: You are initializing datetimepicker only after first click. And because datetimepicker only open after click, this is expected behaviour (first click initializes it, second opens it). So why are you wrapping it inside a click handler?  EDIT: ok i see, to use it on dynamic element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rebinding the datepicker event each time you click `orderDate`.  You only need to bind the datepicker once.  You can achieve this by putting it in the     `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#orderDate").datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                minDate: date,
                locale: 'nl'
   });
});
```

From my comments, you can rebind in the success function within your AJAX call:

```
success: function(data) {
         $.get("/some-domain/shoppingcart/show", function(cart){ 
         $(".shopping-cart").html(cart);
         BindDatePicker(); 
       });


function BindDatePicker() {
    $("#orderDate").datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
                minDate: date,
                locale: 'nl'
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello Darren, the problem is then that the datepicker is not working anymore after it is rerendered by the Ajax response.

Comment: @zeroke - since you are replacing the HTML in the shopping cart after the AJAX request it may have lost it's event handler, try placing it in the document ready like I've shown you, alternatively try rebinding after the success function.

Comment: Ya, this is for sure the way to go, using the success callback

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the date picker control in the ajax response after some delay because the dom might not get updated at the point of initializing. So put a settimeout in success function and then intialize the date picker in it.